# How to refresh jQuery append with table data to a GridView on a button click

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, html-table, webmethod

Here is the scenario, while click on a search button, appending the content of a GridView control with html table data(td) , the html table's data loading from a WebMethod. The problem is, when each click of Search button, the GridView appending the table data with same row of records, is there any way to avoid that?

jQuery

```
    $("#dialog_link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();               
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",
            url: "CustomerSearch.aspx/SearchCustomer",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ value: $("#search_key").val() }),
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,                   
            success: function (data, status) { 
                var table;
                console.log(data);                       
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    table += "<tr><td class='key' style='display:none'>" + data.d[i].custid + "</td>" +
                                    "<td><a class='custlink' style='text-decoration:none' href=#>" + data.d[i].custname + "</a></td>" +
                                    "<td>" + data.d[i].mobno + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + data.d[i].email + "</td></tr>";
                }
                $("#gvCustomer").append(table);                        
            },
            error: function (data, status, error) {
                //console.log(error)
            },
        });
```

HTML

```
 <div id="search_result" style="margin-top:10px">
     <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomer" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:GridView>
 </div >
```

Comment: Yes, check if the data is already in the grid and don't append it if it is... You can add ids or data attributes to your result and use those attributes to determine if they are already present or not...

Comment: Please show us the code you are using to append data to the `GridView`, and if possible the GridView's markup.